# How to get records based on month and Year (Ignore day) - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write one query I can check if the payment is done till the certificate date.

E.g I have two columns with date.

```
CertificateDate : 2016-03-26
LastPaymentDate : 2015-08-06
```

In this case the payment is not done as the certificate date is more than last payment.So how can i check this condition and I want this record.

```
CertificateDate : 2016-03-26
LastPaymentDate : 2016-04-15
```

In this case the payment is done so this should not come in my query results.

One this I can use is datePart = Month + Year but then I find difficulty in getting the < or > query over to that record.

Query : I want to get all those records whose payment is not done till march 2016. If the certificate is generated then the payment should be till that certificate date.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare just the year and month portions, you can use the date part functions.  There is one simple method:

```
where year(LastPaymentDate) * 100 + month(LastPaymentDate) <= 201603
```

However, I think it is even easier to just use date arithmetic:

```
where LastPaymentDate < '2016-04-01'
```

or

```
where LastPaymentDate <  dateadd(day, 1, '2016-03-31')
```